# Issues with resizing on my website

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm very new to coding in HTML and CSS and I have been trying to teach myself but I am struggling that being said I have been able to create this so far:

https://dimensionmediaml.000webhostapp.com/

Now the issue I have is that this website will work fine as long as it is being used on a certain sized monitor but anything smaller (have not been able to test anything larger) and the elements of the page end up looking like they are in the wrong positions

The site has proved to work at a resolution of 1920 x 1080

Any help would be really appreciated

Once again I am very new to this so please be patient with me :)
I have attached the code below and before people rip on me for putting the bootstrap code into the CSS sheet, it was the only way to get elements to display normally on my monitor when uploading the site to the server

HTML and CSS:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_-tn2aR7tHXakZZQ1FleHVveDg?usp=sharing

Comment: You can search for responsive design at one search engine.

Comment: Add (only) the related code inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have Bootstrap but you don't override the css by using  the way you did. Copy the styles you want and make a new document and name it custom.css, then upload that to the css folder on your server. Here is how to change the code in your html

```html
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS: You can use this stylesheet to override any Bootstrap styles and/or apply your own styles -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score -1):

Using width, height, top, bottom etc as percentages will never solve your problem. You must learn with @media queries in CSS3. Please visit this link http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Answers should stand on their own. Please include information from those links in your answer.

Comment: I recommended him to learn responsive web designing from the above mentioned link. So shall i put all the tutorial here?